# Android: Unexplained crashes when the app is reopened after a while

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have a bunch of activities A->B->C->D and they all work well. I have tested them with and without internet, multiple configurations and I have triggered the screen to rotate in every of them to see if they would crash. They didn't

But on my Android phone (not emulator), after a while that the app is in the background, if I open it back (either by recents or by my main menu), I get a series of unexplicable crashes. It's literally activity D crashes, goes to C. C crashes, goes to B. B crashes, goes to A. A crashes, resets, and opens fine. It drives me nuts.

It's always `NullPointerException` on objects, like these ones:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.getfoodie.foodie/net.getfoodie.foodie.ui.exploremenu.MenuFragmentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.getfoodie.foodie.ui.exploremenu.MenuGridAdapter.<init>(MenuGridAdapter.java:71)
at net.getfoodie.foodie.ui.exploremenu.MenuFragment.onActivityCreated(MenuFragment.java:75)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1794)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1917)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:544)
at net.getfoodie.foodie.ui.exploremenu.MenuFragmentActivity.onStart(MenuFragmentActivity.java:89)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1189)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5436)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
... 12 more
```

And for example, the error above is because of a null object from the parse sdk. But the object has already been fetched during the OnCreate of the activity, and I guess it gets lost when the activity is recreated? although I make sure that I fetch it in my `OnCreate()`, and I tested the rotation?

What do you think this is due to? Am I missing something in my app lifecycle?

And more importantly, how can I trigger the "activity kill/sleep" on my Android emulator so I can reproduce the issue and actually try to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the code from `net.getfoodie.foodie.ui.exploremenu.MenuGridAdapter`?  There is a nullpointerexception there somewhere. `MenuFragment.onActivityCreated` would also be helpful.

Comment: @JamesMcCracken I could but they're pretty big (500 lines of code here). The thing is, everytime I fix one, a new one pops up later down. But I can't trigger these errors on my emulator, that's the real issue...

Comment: If you're getting this error after coming back to your app after an extended time, your application has likely been destroyed altogether.  This is different from simply rotating a screen and having an activity recreated.  It is recreating your entire application so any data the activity is using that is somehow stored in a singleton or statically won't be there until you populate it again.

Comment: so where does that fall in the activity lifecycle? How do I know I have to recreate the app? Is there any Android doc around it?

Comment: The activity lifecycle will look exactly the same.  Your `Application.onCreate()` will be hit again so you can do any singleton or data initialization you need there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activities not on screen are frequently killed by Android for memory.  When coming back to an Activity via recents, the most recent activity will be launched but if it was killed it will have no context-  it will get the intent it was launched with but have no static variables or singletons assigned to previous values.  This causes problems for a lot of apps.  The solution is to either allow any activity to fill out these values somehow, or to detect this case and launch an appropriate activity with CLEAR_TOP set to kill the old state.

Oh, and to reproduce it all you need is force stop from the activites manager settings.  Go to activity D, then force stop.  Then return via recents.

As an example-  I have an app with a LoginActivity, and a MainActivity.  MainActivity assumes LoginActivity has set up a user singleton.  My code in MainActivity is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  if(User.getCurrentUser() == null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;
  }
  //Continue on with onCreate for this activity
}
```

This will relaunch the login activity if the User object wasn't set up.

Comment: that makes sense. Do you have any code that illustrates a proper way of implementing what you're describing?

Comment: Its very customized to the application.  I put an example of one way to handle it in my answer, it will relaunch the application from the original activity.  That may not be the best way for you to do it, it depends on how easily recreated your state it.

Comment: I know this isn't the best solution! But for the existing app which hasn't handled app state restoration on configuration change etc. the above way is dramatically easy!! Thanks!